# How do I add values in dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

I'm making an iOS notes taking app which requires a title and notes. I have a `textField` for my title and `textView` for my notes. I then add these two in an array and append them in my `tableView` where we can see the title and notes. The code I'm using appends all my notes in `tableView` and show the same for all the title. I know I have to use a `dictionary` for that but how can I implement that ? This is the code of VC which has the `textView` and `textField`

```
@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{
        list.append(textField.text!)
        list2.append(notesField.text!)
}
```

where `list` and `list2` are empty `array`
In my `tableView` I have expandable cells which have a `textView` to show the content of `list2` and the code for that VC is :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    textView.text = list2.joined(separator: "\n")

}
```

Comment: Read the Swift Language Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take an array of dictionary

```
var arrOfDict = [[String :AnyObject]]()
var dictToSaveNotest = [String :AnyObject]()

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{
  dictToSaveNotest .updateValue(textField.text! as AnyObject, forKey: "title")
  dictToSaveNotest .updateValue(NotesField.text! as AnyObject, forKey: "notesField")
  arrOfDict.append(dictToSaveNotest)
}
```

And just populate it in the tableView Data source method By just make two outlet in the tableViewCell Class titleLable and notesLabel

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! yourTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = arrayOfDict[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String!
        cell.notesLabel.text = arrayOfDict[indexPath.row]["notesField"] as! String!

        return cell
    }
```

Note : I have not tested it on the code , but hope it will work definitely.
       All the best .

Answer (score 1):

You add an element to a dictionary in Swift by assigning:

```
var dict = [String : String]()

let title = "My first note"
let body = "This is the body of the note"

dict[title] = body // Assigning the body to the value of the key in the dictionary

// Adding to the dictionary
if dict[title] != nil {
    print("Ooops, this is not to good, since it would override the current value") 

    /* You might want to prefix the key with the date of the creation, to make 
    the key unique */

} else {
// Assign the value of the key to the body of the note
    dict[title] = body
}
```

You can then loop through the dictionary by using tuples:

```
for (title, body) in dict {
    print("\(title): \(body)")
}
```

If you are only interested in the body or the title, you can simply ignore the other by replacing title or body with _ like this:

```
for (_, body) in dict {
    print("The body is: \(body)")
}
// and
for (title, _) in dict {
    print("The title is: \(title)")
}
```

The title/body could also be accessed by the keys or values properties of the dictionary:

```
for title in dict.keys {
    print("The title is: \(title)")
}
// and
for body in dict.values {
    print("The body is: \(body)")
}
```